# What does the "f" prefix of some gcc command line options mean

Tags: gcc

Some gcc command line options come with an `f` prefix.

For example [there is](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-no-pie) `-no-pie` switch, but I have also seen `-fno-pie` being used (eg in [this patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9399969/)).

I could not find documentation for the latter form, so I can not deduce what change the `f` actually make.

There are plenty more options that has only the `f` version, for example `-ffreestanding` or `-fcall-used-reg`.

Comment: I've always assumed it stands for "flag", but that isn't even true for all of them.

Comment: According to the manual, it appears that `-pie` is a [link time option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) where `-fpie` is a [code gen option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html). I'm not sure if this holds in general. The manual also mentions `-f` as a common prefix for commands  [in the introduction](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html); so I don't think it has any meaning beyond that.

Comment: To produce a position independent executable, you need to set both `-fpie` when compiling, and `-pie` when linking.

Comment: @Mankarse but, confusingly, the GCC accepts `gcc file.c -o file -fno-pie -no-pie`, for example. So, it seems to consume the `-no-pie` option that is specified as being a [linker](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-no-pie) command. _However_, if you try to explicitly pass it with `-Wl,-no-pie` I get other linker errors about not finding `libgcc_s`. It's hard to keep straight.